# Inject property value into annotation field

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-web

I'm developing my rest API and I would want to have a dynamic list of endpoints. I'm using following approach:

```java
@Controller("/")
public class Resource {

    @PostMapping(path = {"request1", "request2"})
    public Mono<ResponseEntity> postData(ServerHttpRequest request) {
        return Mono.fromSupplier(() -> ResponseEntity.ok().build());
    }
}
```

So I would like to know if it's possible to retrieve values for path field of PostMapping dynamically from the properties?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Annotation variables must be compile-time constants, so you cannot inject any variable in there. Why not create a wildcard endpoint a-la ``@PostMapping(value = "/{id}")`` and use @PathVariable? Then you can filter out the endpoints which are not in your application.properties.

Comment: Directly in the controller? It will also work but I thought there was a possible solution like I've proposed

Comment: Yes. You can make use of the ``@Value`` annotation, e.g.: ``@Value("${helloworld.endpoint}") String endpoint;``

Comment: Actually, it won't solve my problem because in the annotation field I can add only constants

Comment: see my answer below. hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@RestController
public class Resource {
    @Value("${helloworld.endpoints}") String endpoints = "";

    @GetMapping(value = "/maybe/{wildcard}")
    public Mono<ResponseEntity> post(@PathVariable(value = "wildcard") String path) {
        boolean ok = Arrays.asList(endpoints.split(";")).contains(path);
        if (ok)
            return Mono.fromSupplier(() -> ResponseEntity.ok().build());
        else
            return Mono.fromSupplier(() -> ResponseEntity.notFound().build());
    }
}
```

application.properties:

```
helloworld.endpoints=request1;request2;request3
```